# Does an assumption need to be true after a proof?

Tags: proof-writing

If I start a proof by saying:

Assume $a^3=b$

and end up proving something with it, will the proof hold for when $a^3\neq b$? Would that be a valid proof for all $a$ and $b$ baring any other domain issues?

Comment: "Assuming $a^3=b$. Then clearly $a^3+1=b^3+1$." Do you we should be able to conclude "$a^3+1=b^3+1$" for all $a, b$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, no. For instance, if one assumes $x=2y$, one can prove $x^2=4y^2$, and the result is true in other cases (like if $x=-2y$), but it is not true in general (take $x=y=1$, for example).